# PyQt5: Issues with Resizing and Rendering After Accessing Child Widget's HWND

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I've been working with PyQt5 and encountered some issues with my application's window behavior. My application's main window consists of a central widget, which is a QWidget container. This container includes a QStackedWidget. However, I've run into a problem when attempting to obtain the HWND (window handle) of a child widget within the QStackedWidget.

After retrieving the HWND of the child widget, the application behaves unexpectedly in two ways:

Resizing Issue: The main window loses its ability to be resized. It seems as though the resizing feature is disabled or not recognized anymore.
Rendering Issue Upon Minimize/Maximize: When I minimize the main window and then maximize it again, the content stops rendering. The window appears static and does not update its contents.
I understand that sharing the code might provide more context, but unfortunately, the codebase is too large and complex to share in its entirety. It's difficult to pinpoint the exact sections relevant to these issues without potentially omitting crucial details.

Given this complexity, I would greatly appreciate if someone could guide me towards understanding why these issues are happening and suggest potential fixes. Any insights or directions to investigate would be incredibly helpful as I navigate these challenges.

Thank you in advance for any assistance or advice you can provide.

I expected that by obtaining the HWND, I would be able to perform additional native Windows operations on the child widget without affecting the overall behavior of the main window. Specifically, I anticipated that the main window would retain its ability to be resized and that the content would continue to render correctly after minimizing and maximizing

Comment: Accessing the win id of child widgets is a rare necessity. What do you actually need to do with it (the "additional native windows operations")? Also, if you're unable to reproduce the issue with a proper [mre], it probably (not necessarily) means that there may be other issues in your code, possibly not (or only partially) related to the access to the window handle. If a basic example doesn't reproduce the issue, try to get a larger "view" on your program structure, and gradually add those aspects of it that may be related to widget handling.

Comment: Alternatively, do the opposite: create a copy of your code or project, and gradually strip out anything that doesn't seem related to the problem (such as property changes of input widgets, button click connections, etc.) until the issue doesn't happen anymore, then restore the last step and remove anything else that doesn't seem related to it. In either of these ways you should be able to get a proper MRE, and even find a solution to the problem on your own.

Comment: While technically allowed, embedding "alien" windows from external processes that do not use Qt is not officially supported and suffers many issues (you did read the [warnings in the documentation](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#createWindowContainer), didn't you?). Especially for modern systems and UI toolkits, 99% of the times you'll face some problems that cannot be worked around (partially or completely), and under certain conditions it may just not be possible at all: AFAIR, it's completely impossible with Wayland, but in some cases it wasn't even possible or reliable on X11/Xorg.

Comment: @Pythonic007 As already pointed out, the Qt APIs are unreliable and in any case *do not officially support embedding foreign windows at all*. See: [Issues with the current Qt APIs](https://gist.github.com/torarnv/c5dfe2d2bc0c089910ce#issues-with-the-current-qt-apis) and [QTBUG-44404](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-44404?focusedCommentId=272902&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-272902). You should therefore expect to encounter problems that will probably never be fixed if you continue using these APIs.